# Kubernetes Dynamic Configmapping in StatefulSet

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, minikube, configmap

In Kubernetes you have the ability to dynamically grab the name of a pod and reference it in a yaml file (Pod Field) like so:

```
env:
- name: POD_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.name
```

and reference it later in the yaml file like so:

```
- name: FOO
  value: $(POD_NAME)-bar
```

Where in the case of a StatefulSet the value of foo may be something like "app_thing-0-bar, app_thing-1-bar ... etc". However this doesn't seem to work in dynamically setting the name of a configmap. For example, the following configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app_thing-0-config
data:
  FOO: BAR
```

and this in the StatefulSet deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: app_thing
.
.
.
.
.
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
      name: $(POD_NAME)-config
```

will not reference the configmap correctly as it doesn't seem to like the $() syntax. Is there any way to do this without resorting to init containers and entrypoint scripting?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly there is a tool that can make it work. It's called [RELOADER](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader):

> **Problem:**  We would like to watch if some change happens in ConfigMap and/or Secret; then perform a rolling upgrade on relevant
>   DeploymentConfig, Deployment, Daemonset and Statefulset
>
> **Solution:**  Reloader can watch changes in ConfigMap and Secret and do rolling upgrades on Pods with their associated DeploymentConfigs,
>   Deployments, Daemonsets and Statefulsets.

You can find all the necessary info in the link above.
Also if you'd need more details than you can check the [documentation](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader/tree/master/docs).

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Just resorted to writing bash scripts that do a bunch of text replacing